# Rails 4 Rating Inside Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rating

I'm quite new to Rails and was wondering what option would be best with a system of rating for users:

```
user has_many reviews
```

Each review contains a rating.

In order to display reviews count and average rating, is it a better idea to add these columns to the user model and update them through after_save callbacks on the review model or simply define functions that will use COUNT and AVERAGE, but will hit the DB everytime?

Comment: If you add `belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true` to the review model and add `reviews_count` column to users then rails will update that count automatically.

Comment: I agree about the reviews count. With respect to the average rating, i would add a numeric field (e.g. avg_rating:float) to the User model and update it with a `before_save` callback on the review model, possibly avoiding hitting the db again for all reviews, thus with something like `user.avg_rating = ((user.avg_rating * user.reviews_count) + review.rating) / (user.reviews_count + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely better to add columns, especially if you're sorting on them or showing them in a list.

Agreed with the column definitions by @Halogen

I tend to put these in methods on after_save to make sure all objects are validly saved first.

```
after_save :set_reviews_average, set_reviews_count

# Note: update_column won't trigger callbacks

def set_reviews_average
  update_column(:reviews_average, reviews.average(:rating)) 
end

def set_reviews_count
  update_column(:reviews_count, reviews.count) 
end
```